# Is there a quick way on the iPhone simulator to jump between international languages?

Tags: iphone, ios, localization, internationalization, ios-simulator

Is there a quick way on the iPhone simulator to jump between international languages?

Just noting when testing that it is a bit slow having to (a) exit the app, (b) manually change the language settings via the settings application, (c) restart the application in xcode [as it crashes when I try to bring it back from background]

Comment: So you want it to NOT simulate what you have to do on the iPhone?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There isn't directly afaik atm :/
But there is this: http://indiedevstories.com/2011/11/08/a-reusable-localization-manager-class-for-ios/.

Which should do what you want? :)